# How can I remove the "Show Feed" section from the top of the Account page?

Tags: account, chatter-feed

Since this isn't used at all, I consider it clutter and hope there is a way to hide, or remove it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to Setup--> Chatter-->Feed Tracking -->Select Account --> Uncheck "Enable Feed Tracking"
[image]

Comment: Does this have side-effects besides the desired impact stated in the OP?

Comment: @Adrian Larson, no side effects for me. Seems to have worked perfectly.